# Error: Cannot read properties of null reading "checked"

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I'm having trouble fully wiring on my Django applications submit button, it seems that the JS function does not understand which checked boxes to look for
all the console returns are "cannot read properties of null, reading "checked" I'm assuming its something with the function defining but I cannot seem to get it working

Heres the code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        {% load static%}
        {% block content%}
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'IMG/favicon.ico' %}"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'CSS/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'CSS/jquery-ui.css' %}">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'JS/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
        <title>Task List</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'JS/jquery-ui.min.js' %}"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script>
            let _csrf = '{{csrf_token}}';
            function submit_delete() {
                var listItems = $("#list li input");
                var checkedListItems = [];
                listItems.each(function() {
                    if (document.getElementById(this.id).checked) {
                        checkedListItems.push(getTaskId(this.id));
                        console.log(checkedListItems);
                    }
                })
          $.ajax({
            headers: { "X-CSRFToken": _csrf },
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ptm/item_delete",
            data: {
                'deleteList[]': checkedListItems
            }
          }).done(location.reload());
          
        }

        function getTaskId(str) {
            return str.split('-')[1];
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="logo" class="border-success border border-3 rounded-2" style="width: 61.rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <img class="card-img" src="{% static '/IMG/Logo.png' %}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="taskList" class="card">
            {% if task_list %}
            <ul class="list-group" id="list">
                {% for item in task_list %}
                <li class="list-group-item" id='tdList'>
                    <input id="check-{{ item.id }}" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input me-1" value="">
                    <label class='d-flex w-100 justify-content-between'>
                        <h2 class="form-check-label" for="check-{{ item.id }}">{{ item.title }}</h2>
                        <small class='text-muted'>{{ item.date }}</small>
                        <input size='3'>
                    </label>
                    <h5 class="form-check-label">{{ item.description }}</h5>

                </li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% else %}
            <p>There are no current tasks assigned to this department.</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div id="taskEnter" class="card-footer">
            <div class="d-grid mx-auto">
                {% if task_list %}
                <button type="button" onclick="submit_delete()" value='delete' class="btn btn-success btn-lg d-grid" value='delete'><i class="">Submit</i></button>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    {% endblock %}
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the part:

```
document.getElementById(this.id).checked
```

`document.getElementById(this.id)` evaluates to `null`, which doesn't have any properties, hence the exception you're getting. You're effectively doing `null.checked` which won't work.

It looks like you're trying to iterate over the checkboxes and determine whether they're checked or not. I'm reasonably confident that `this` inside the function you wrote will just refer to the `window` object, so calling `this.id` won't give you a checkbox id. You have actually already fetched all of the checkboxes (you're iterating over them!) so there's no need to refetch each one manually. Just do:

```js
listItems.each(function(listItem) {
    if (listItem.checked) {
        checkedListItems.push(getTaskId(listItem.id));
        console.log(checkedListItems);
    }
})
```

Note that the function takes as argument the individual listItem (confusingly named since they're actually checkboxes but I'm following your nomenclature here) that `each` is currently iterating over. Which is what you need.

Comment: That worked in stopping that error but now that onclick function just does nothing instead of deleting the checked boxed item id

Comment: That sounds like a separate question.

Comment: I think you'll find that [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) calls its function argument with a `this` value set to the DOM element being processed.

Comment: @traktor You're right. Strange that there appear to be checkboxes without an id – they should all have one.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a child combinator ('>') to the element selector used in the first line of function `submit_delete`:

```
var listItems = $("#list li > input");
```

- or use a more precise selector of your own devisement.

As posted there appear to be descendant `input` elements of `.list li` of form `<input size='3'>` that don't have an `id` attribute. Processing these in `each` returns `null` from `getElementById` and throws the error that `checked` can't be a property of `null`.

**About `each`**

JAuery's [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function fires its callback with a `this` value set to the element being processed during the iteration. The element is also provided to the callback as its second argument. Given elements in HTML should have unique id values:

- For elements referred to by `this` that have `id` values, using `this` for the element is simpler than calling `getElementById(this.id)`.
- For elements (referred to by `this`) that do not have an id, `!this.id`) is a  simpler conditional expression than `getElementById(this.id)===null`.
- Filtering out elements that should not be mnatched during selection is preferable to filtering them out later.